# CSS: How to display an image in the background of a fixed-width, centered div?

Tags: html, css, css-position

I've written a web page where the content sits within a fixed-width, centered div, like so:

```
<div style='width:800px; margin: -5px auto 0px auto;' >    
This is a fixed-width centered div!
</div>
```

Everything was fine until I was asked to put a background image within the div.  Using CSS-background inevitable results in the image being stretched or tiled.  I don't want that.  I want *one* instance of the image with it's upper left-hand corner in the upper left-hand corner of my fixed width div.

I tried to do this several ways.

Here's the first way that doesn't work:

```
<img src='images/background.jpg' alt='background'
 style='position:relative;left:0;top:0;z-index:-1' />
```

In this example, the image is positioned exactly as I want, but the text of the div appears below the image.

Here's the second way that doesn't work:

```
<img src='images/background.jpg' alt='background'
 style='position:absolute;left:0;top:0;z-index:-1' />
```

Using absolute positioning, the text appears over the image as I want.  However, the image is now in the upper left-hand corner of the page.  This is to be expected because there is no other element with absolute positioning.  I understand that the solution should be to set the position of the fixed-width centered div to absolute as well.  However, when I do this, my fixed-width div is no longer centered:

My div is no longer centered!

How can I write my HTML and CSS so that I have text within a fixed-width, centered div with a background image behind the text?

Comment: @antisanity, thanks for the answer using the `background-repeat` CSS.  I am still interested in knowing if there is a way of using CSS positioning with the `img` tag.  I believe that this would be a great thing to be able to use for future endeavors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Using CSS-background inevitable results in the image being stretched
>   or tiled.

Yes, background-images repeat -*by default*. However, you can *explicitly* set [background-repeat](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/background-repeat) to `no-repeat`

```
<div style='width:800px; margin: -5px auto 0px auto;background-image:url('images/background.jpg');background-repeat:no-repeat;' >    
This is a fixed-width centered div!
</div>
```

**[Edit]** Vertical clipping can be resolved by setting your div's [min-height](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/min-height) to the image's pixel-height. This will ensure that your div is always *at least* as tall as your image. This is the ideal solution.

However, if your image is conceivably *wider* than your div's 800px static width, you'll need to go back to the nested image solution... Make the div `position:relative` and the image `position:absolute` and the image's top/left will be relative to the div rather than the page. In combination with a [z-index](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/z-index) `-1` on the image, you should be good to go ([fiddle demonstrating an un-clipped image](http://jsfiddle.net/Uwu2G/))

Comment: +1: This is very close to what I want, and it takes care of the case where the div is bigger than the image.  However, this code results in the image being cropped whenever the div is smaller than the image.

Answer (score 1):

You can use "overflow:visible;" to make sure the image doesn't get cropped.

```
<div style='width:800px; overflow: visible; margin: -5px auto 0px auto;background-image:url('images/background.jpg');background-repeat:no-repeat;' >    
This is a fixed-width centered div!
</div>
```

Or, alternatively, try making the "min-height" of the div the same as the height of your image. I've used 300px in the example below, but you should change that to whatever size your image is.

```
<div style='width:800px; min-height: 300px; margin: -5px auto 0px auto;background-image:url('images/background.jpg');background-repeat:no-repeat;' >    
This is a fixed-width centered div!
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can configure the `background` property with the shorthand:

```
background: <background-color> url(<background-image>) <background-position-x> <background-position-y> <background-repeat>;
```

As follows:

```
<div style='position:fixed; width:800px; margin: -5px auto 0px auto; border: 2px solid #ccc; height: 5em; background: rgba(255,255,255,0.5) url(http://davidrhysthomas.co.uk/img/dexter.png) 0 0 no-repeat;'>    
This is a fixed-width centered div!
</div>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/NFSAH/).

Reference:

- [CSS `background` at the MDC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/background).